# how to load image from absolute server url ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to render image as below but the code does not show the image. But when I hit the url it shows the image

```
<img src={'http://domainname.com/'+image}/>
```

Comment: What is in the image variable? Make sure it is a string like 'my_image.png'. Also, be sure to add an alt attribute or you'll get complaints in your console.

You could also use src={\`http:// domainname.com/${image_name_and_extension}\`}

Comment: yes image variable contains string like 'image.png' .I tried your suggestion it still does not show the image. It only shows image when given default nextjs '/static/images/' directory

Comment: Does an image in fact exist at that URL? Try using a predefined static image URL with a known image that works. It might be that the image at that URL does not exist.

Comment: oh thankyou. The image works now. The problem was the image url from free hosting that had problems. changing the server fixed it